# Order by only the numeric part of a string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a column called `Number` populated with this data (column is nchar):

```
1
2
1091
3
20
2B
```

I want a select statement that give this order:

```
1
2
2B
3
20
1091
```

How I can accomplish this? Thanks everybody for your help

(EDITED)

Comment: An order that changes values from 2B to 3B?

Comment: In first part you have 2B in second 3B. Typo ?

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind that ordering?  From what I see, SQL can't be instructed to do what your asking.

Comment: I was assuming that there was a couple of typos there.

Comment: Could you specify the ordering further. How about `[b, 2, 20, 2b, 20b,  2b0, 2z, z2, 2z, 2zb]`? Is it hexadecimal or everything-until-an-eventual-alphachar-is-numeric-and-the-alphachars represents fractions?

Comment: Why on earth are you storing this as `nchar`? I question both fixed length and the necessity for Unicode.

Comment: alpha-char is entered eventually, but i need to handle that situation faester

Comment: varchar type is better for this purpose Aaron?

Comment: Yes, `varchar` would be better. Though you may consider a computed column or otherwise extracting the number if you are going to be ordering or searching on the number alone.

Comment: ok Aaron, i will do the change to varchar. I think dont need the computed column since i dont do number-alone search. Many many thanks 4 ur help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can perform some tricks by converting to a numeric after you discover the location of the first non-numeric. Appending a random character at the end makes it treat all strings the same even if the original string did not contain an alphabetic.

```
SELECT [Number] FROM dbo.TableName 
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, LEFT(Number, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', Number + 'z')-1));
```

Comment: Aaron - I do think it is important to give future visitors to the question the right terminology to use.   Sometimes a link to documentation is a bonus and this case, almost required.  A search for `Sql Server` and `convert` pulls up a lot of false hits.. I *think* it converts to an integer.  The `-1` in your expression confuses me totally.  IF the code does what I /think/ it does -- that is, extract out just the numeric part of the `Number`, then `32a`, `32fred`  and `32c` would come out unordered -- since the alphabetic part isn't considered.

Comment: @Jeremy a solution to a coding question should not have to include the definition for every single function used in the solution. Do I really need to write a paragraph on what CONVERT does? The OP certainly didn't think so, and you are probably the only reader who would expect that, too. If further sorting is *required* then it should be stated in the question. If I *assume* that a certain sorting should be required, as you suggest, then the answer does *more* than the OP asked. So in the end, do I think this answer helps the OP more than you pointing to Oracle and MySQL natural sorts? Yes.

Comment: @AaronBertrand -- **So in the end, do I think this answer helps the OP more than you pointing to Oracle and MySQL natural sorts? Yes** This was never under discussion.

Comment: @Jeremy pretty sure down below you said that an answer pointing to documentation was better than a "magic incantation"... should one not assume you were also suggesting that your answer with links to natural join techniques for other RDBMSes was also better?

Comment: @AaronBertrand -- Since you provided an exact solution, and I could only provide a *here is the next step in your search for an answer*, there was no question that your answer was better.  **However** -- had no correct answer come up, then the term *Natural Sort* (which I provided) would have at least given the OP the name of what he needed.  Depending on his research and database skills, the OP could have used the techniques I pointed to to form his own solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called a **NATURAL SORT**, which is different from the regular sort that most systems give.  I've found a handful of posts here at Stack Overflow that covers natural sorts in various popular SQL engines, including one brief discussion about `SQL Server`.

The ideas here may get you started on a solution.

[Oracle: How can I implement a "natural" order-by in a SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219982/oracle-how-can-i-implement-a-natural-order-by-in-a-sql-query)

You might have to change the syntax for your SQL engine though.

Found another version for MYSQL:

[Natural Sort in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql)

Can't find any for SQL Server yet.

**Edit3**

Ah, this one covers some SQL Server ideas too:

[Natural Sort in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql)

Comment: @AaronBertrand -- The OP needed a natural sort, though the OP didn't use that term my name.  Since SQL engines don't have a natural sort built in, one has to be made using an expression.  My links covered different ways people have gotten a natural sort in various forms of SQL.  One of them could have been adapted.

Comment: Well they didn't need it in Oracle or MySQL, and the MySQL answer doesn't seem to have any valid answers for SQL Server either, as you suggest. The closest I found was one that contained `MID` but that's an Access function, not SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Use PATINDEX, check this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/443ad/7) code.  @AaronBertrand just answered as I was testing.

Just to add some more value and info, check [this SQLServerCentral link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic693752-149-1.aspx) as there you can find more answers.

And check this [Natural (human alpha-numeric) sort in Microsoft SQL 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509/natural-human-alpha-numeric-sort-in-microsoft-sql-2005), lot of useful answers and variations.

Comment: Can some of the downvoters comment on what is wrong? I was just adding some more information on the already useful answer...thanks

Comment: EH, someones been down-vote happy on this question.  Have a +1 for providing documentation, not just a magic incantation answer.

Comment: I didn't down-vote (yet) but usually if you are trying to add information to an existing answer, you add a comment, not an additional answer.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, when you posted your answer I was about to post mine, see the time difference. Then I took some time to add these links. Is not the first time I see same or almost same answer with less than minute difference. And even comments like "beat me for X seconds" and alike.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher what answer on this page is from magic incantation?

Comment: @AaronBertrand -- `Incantation` is a slang term used in some circles for a technically correct answer that offers no explanation as to *why* a given answer works.  While I have no idea that your answer does exactly was the OP asked for, it doesn't help him solve similar problems in the future.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher my answer includes some text. Could you explain to me how I could improve that text to give even more information about what the query is actually doing? Do you know that there is a pretty formally stated policy against link-only answers on StackOverflow, in case you're suggesting that an answer that points to a link is somehow a better answer than a posted and working piece of code right on the page?

Comment: @AaronBertrand -- Link-only answers to non-Stack Overflow are frowned on because if the original site vanishes, all record vanishes.  Duplicate questions, on the other hand, get a 'link-only' answer.  I tried to stay with SO-based answers when I could.  Since you asked for comments on your answer, I'll put them there.

Comment: @Jeremy An "answer" that just points to another question/answer on StackOverflow shouldn't be an answer. That's a comment (or a vote to close, if it's a true duplicate).